# Dynamic procedure in view in SQL Server 2012

Tags: stored-procedures, dynamic, view, sql-server-2012

I have a problem with a view taken from a dynamic procedure.

Here is some code to reproduce my problem (note that this is a simplified version of what I try to handle.)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataTable]
(
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DataTable_id]  DEFAULT (newid()),
    [Order_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DataType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DataValue] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_DataTable] 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('F8BB99BB-FE94-4161-B449-00C5E81FA991', 'Order_No', '123')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('E0C7C86E-74B9-4F37-AF41-5BD82A0CE2FF', 'Order_No', '124')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('988E3B5A-B9FA-486C-9755-E4F7AF1A9964', 'Order_No', '125')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('2690A51B-5CBC-42F9-9F76-94D7F9BF2FD4', 'Order_No', '126')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('F8BB99BB-FE94-4161-B449-00C5E81FA991', 'order_Status', 'OK')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('E0C7C86E-74B9-4F37-AF41-5BD82A0CE2FF', 'order_Status', 'OK')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('988E3B5A-B9FA-486C-9755-E4F7AF1A9964', 'order_Status', 'NOK')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('2690A51B-5CBC-42F9-9F76-94D7F9BF2FD4', 'order_Status', 'pending')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('F8BB99BB-FE94-4161-B449-00C5E81FA991', 'Level1_Status', '2')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('E0C7C86E-74B9-4F37-AF41-5BD82A0CE2FF', 'Level1_Status', '5')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('988E3B5A-B9FA-486C-9755-E4F7AF1A9964', 'Level2_Status', '3')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('2690A51B-5CBC-42F9-9F76-94D7F9BF2FD4', 'Level2_Status', '1')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('F8BB99BB-FE94-4161-B449-00C5E81FA991', 'customer', 'John')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('E0C7C86E-74B9-4F37-AF41-5BD82A0CE2FF', 'customer', 'Nancy')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('988E3B5A-B9FA-486C-9755-E4F7AF1A9964', 'location', 'Germany')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Order_ID, DataType, DataValue) 
VALUES ('2690A51B-5CBC-42F9-9F76-94D7F9BF2FD4', 'information', 'very important')
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_order_List] 
as 
begin 
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX); 

    SELECT
       @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(DataType) 
    FROM 
       dbo.DataTable 
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

    set @query =
       'select * from
          (SELECT Order_ID, DataType, DataValue FROM dbo.DataTable ) ps 
           PIVOT ( MIN (DataValue) FOR DataType in (' + @cols + ')) AS pvt'

    execute (@query);
end
GO
```

In SQL Server 2008 R2 it was possible to put a view over the procedure, so I can access the data in the format needed and everything was fine.

Please take note, that normally I don't do `select *` in my View, but join, subselect and convert my data and some other tables, to get my final result, depending on my needs.

```
exec sp_serveroption @server = 'YOURSERVER\SQL2012' 
   ,@optname = 'DATA ACCESS' 
   ,@optvalue = 'TRUE' 
go

create view [dbo].[vw_order_list]
as
    SELECT a.*
    FROM openquery([YourServer\SQL2012], 'SET FMTONLY OFF;exec TestDatabase.dbo.sp_order_List') AS a                         
GO
```

Now my company wants to upgrade to SQL Server 2012 and here my problems starts.

When I try to create the view I get this error message:

> Error :11514 – The metadata could not be determined because statement
>   in procedure contains dynamic SQL. Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS
>   clause to explicitly describe the result set.

The problem is, that the columns are generated automatically depending on the values in `DataType`, so that I can't give the view a fix Result `Set`.

I already tried everything which came into my mind and tried to find that problem with google without success.

Please feel free to ask, if something is unclear or if you have any suggestions.
Using a view is not required, but would make my life a lot easier.

Just keep in mind, that I need to join different tables depending on users request in the software.

Ideas I already had, but had issues with:

- something with a temp table (didn't get it to work)
- creating the view by procedure dynamically. The problem is, that there is a chance that somebody is requesting the view while I try to recreate it with the procedure. Don't know how I can stop this from happening.

Comment: From what I read I think you're out of luck and might want to consider a different approach. You could try your luck and post this at [dba.se] instead.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!